# Q&A Forum - Logic

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not asking for help with coding I'm just asking for somebody to help me come up with an idea of how I would make it.

Basically I want to make a basic Q&A forum, I guess you could say its like Stackoverflow, but not nearly as advanced its just something quick to add onto my website.

I was thinking of just making a default form you fill out to post what you want then it'll just save the POST of all the data into a table in a database and it'll give it an auto_incremented ID. The only thing I can't think of is how I would display all of them on the homepage, make it so it only displays a maximum of 15 posts and then make different pages like Page1,2,3,etc...

Should I check the table for how many rows there are and then save that amount as a variable then make it post them in order from what ID they have? I'm not sure what I could do for comments and everything but I would love your guys help with figuring this out!

As I said this isn't really much about the coding, its more about figuring out the logic behind how I would make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your asking about is termed pagination here's a php tutorial

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Comment: Wow I didn't think it would be that easy. Thats actually really cool man! I will vote your answer as correct after 8 minutes but for now I will give you reputation! Thanks!